# Emulate subwcrev when using git-svn

Tags: bash, git-svn

I use git-svn to interact with an existing SVN repository that contains some C++ projects. subwcrev.exe is used as a pre-build event to update some strings in a C++ header (svnversion.h). These strings get hardcompiled to form some version information for the resulting binary.

Since subwcrev requires .svn metadata to work, the pre-build event is going to fail when used on the git-svn working copy. So I came up with the following bash script which I use as post-commit and post-checkout hooks for my git repository. The script tries to do the same thing as subwcrev based on the output of git svn info (cached in a local file).

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f svninfo ] ; then
    git svn info > svninfo
fi

revision=`sed -e "/Revision/!d" -e "s/Revision: \(.*\)/\1/" svninfo`
lastchange=`sed -e "/Last Changed Rev/!d" -e "s/Last Changed Rev: \(.*\)/\1/" svninfo`
# Get the last changed date, extract timestamp, replaces dashes with slashes
changedate=`sed -e "/Last Changed Date/!d" -e "s/Last Changed Date: \(.\{19\}\).*/\1/" -e "s!-!\\\\\\/!g" svninfo`
now=`date "+%Y\/%m\/%d %H:%M:%S"`

gitcommit=`git show --abbrev-commit | sed -n -e "s/commit //p"`

for entry in $( find -name svnversion_template.h ); do
    newname=`echo $entry|sed -e "s/_template//"`
    sed -e "s/\\\$WCRANGE\\\$/${revision}/" \
        -e "s/\\\$WCREV\\\$/${lastchange}-${gitcommit}/" \
        -e "s/\\\$WCDATE\\\$/${changedate}/" \
        -e "s/\\\$WCNOW\\\$/${now}/" \
        -e "s/\\\$WCURL\\\$/local git repo/" \
        -e "s/\\\$WCMODS.*\\\$/(true)/" \
        -e "s/\\\$WCMIXED.*\\\$/(false)/" \
        $entry > `echo $entry|sed -e "s/_template//"`
done
```

What I cannot really emulate so far is the automatic detection of a local uncommitted changes (based on the last checked out SVN revision) that makes subwcrev so useful.

I am replacing `$WCREV$` with the revision number of the SVN repository (as subwcrev would do) but this time I add my abbreviated git commit hash to identify the code I compiled. My question now is: Is there a way to distinguish in a shell script whether my current HEAD differs from the last fetched SVN revision so that I could omit adding the `-${gitcommit}` part and set `$WCMODS$` to false?

If there were some thing like a `post-"git svn dcommit"` hook, my problem would be solved, too, since then that special hook would create the svnversion.h differently. Can such hook be added somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your points, but start to improve your script first.

```
revision=$(grep -Po "(?<=Revision: ).*" svninfo)
lastchange=$(grep -Po "(?<=Last Changed Rev: ).*" svninfo)
# Get the last changed date, extract timestamp, replaces dashes with slashes
changedate=$(grep -Po "(?<=Last Changed Date: ).{19}" svninfo)
changedate=${changedate//-//}
now=$(date "+%Y\/%m\/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Then, in for loop, could you please explain detail, what result you need? 
Can you show one sample of svnversion_template.h ?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you might have to parse the contents of the `git svn info` query yourself to get what is normally stored in WCREV.  The example results look like this for me:

```
git svn info
Path: .
URL: http://myurl.com/trunk/myrepo
Repository Root: http://myurl.com
Repository UUID: 15fed3e9-81ce-ef4a-a7da-fc36e3df1edc
Revision: 14106
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: myusername
Last Changed Rev: 14106
Last Changed Date: 2015-05-29 10:23:10 -0400 (Fri, 29 May 2015)
```

Now for the second part of your question, whether or not you can tell if your git HEAD matches the latest svn checkout, you'll need to use the command `git diff git-svn` command.  "git-svn" here is the name of the branch that the git-svn program is maintaining, and if everything is up to date, the results will be empty.