# 'SVN_REV' undeclared when build the target in git-svn environment

Tags: svn, makefile, git-svn

I use the following command to get the repository from the svn server:

```
git svn clone ...
```

However when build the specific target, the stdout shows the following:

```
error: 'SVN_REV' undeclared here (not in a function)
__attribute__((used)) u32 sys_fw_info = SVN_REV;
```

Here is the simplified makefile:

```
haha: dirs revision
    -$(MAKE) -C ./src

revision:
    -$(SVNVERSION) . version.tmp build/svnrev.h
```

I have tried the following:

1. If I copy the .svn folder from the normal checkout repository in svn server [since folder I got from git-svn only has .git folder], then I can build the target of haha in the git-svn environment.
2. If I manually do the following command and don't copy the .svn folder:

   ```
   SubWCRev.exe . version.tmp  build/svnrev.h
   ```

The building process still fail... 
Have the following two questions:

1. I don't know if the .svn folder has some dependency with building process?
2. How can I use the git-svn elegantly locally?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if the .svn folder has some dependency with building process?

Indirectly.

You **must** pre-process your sources with `subwcrev` (in order to get variable defined in `svnrev.h`), and subwcrev have to have access to Subversion Working Copy (`SubWCRev.exe .`) for getting svn-based metadata (which doesn't exist in Git's Working Directory)

> How can I use the git-svn elegantly locally?

You have to at least try and inspect output of `git svn info`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954062/emulate-subwcrev-when-using-git-svn) and [answer of @bmv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21575778/960558) in it will help mainly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try the suggestion in that post~~!